# Tomcat application is giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation error

Tags: java, tomcat, hadoop, hdfs

I have a service which writes input stream to a file. Earlier I was writing the file to local machine then it was working fine. But now I want to my service to write input stream to a file in hdfs.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

UserGroupInformation realUser =  UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("mapr");

UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(realUser);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
String fileWriteAt = "maprfs:///mapr/silver1cluster/"+filePath;
Path outpath= new Path(fileWriteAt);
OutputStream os = fs.create(outpath);
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, conf);
```

After deploying the code ...when I m hitting the service with with the url i m getting below error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
    com.api.service.ServiceAction.saveFile(ServiceAction.java:30)
    com.api.service.FileHandling.uploadFile(FileHandling.java:51).
```

ServiceAction.java: 30 line is basically `UserGroupInformation realUser = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("mapr");`